# Missing button in email message inbound email message

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-chatter, salesforce-communities

Email messages having relation with standard and custom Object, I can see Reply, ReplyAll and Forward button in Inbound and Outbound email messages record. To make these buttons visible what configuration work to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Hi to make this button visible you need to add those button the desired objects page layouts.